# Math Values not Calculating Properly

Tags: java, math, system.out

For some reason, I am getting different mathematical values than I should be.  What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40;

regularPay = hourlyWage * hoursWorked - overtimeHours;
overtimePay = 1.5 * hourlyWage * overtimeHours;
totalPay = hourlyWage * hoursWorked + overtimePay;
```

Output:

```
Please enter employee's name: John
Please enter The Dragon's hourly wage: 22.50
Please enter how many hours The Dragon worked: 48.5

John's Wages
Regular Pay: $    1082.75
Overtime Pay: $    286.88
Total Pay: $    1378.13
```

Comment: I should be getting Regular Pay: 900.00, Overtime Page: 286.88, Total Pay: 1186.88.  My overtime value is correct, but not the other values.

Comment: are the variables int?

Comment: Always use brackets. It just makes writing and reading code so much easier

Comment: @RyanS Note that it's customary in the US and, as far as I know, with programming generally, to call `()` parentheses; "brackets" usually refers to square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Your first mistake is using floating point for monetary values, which is going to cause trouble sooner or later. Also, you are missing parentheses from your calculations, as others have noted.

Comment: @Chrylis ah yes, I am aware of that, just a habit to call them brackets. Most people I know in Canada also call them brackets and explicitly call square brackets.. square brackets lol

Comment: Using `BigDecimal` is the recommended way to represent money since floating point numbers always carry small rounding differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Order of operations, just like you learned in basic math. You're calculating

```
(hourlyWage * hoursWorked) - overtimeHours
```

Instead, you want

```
hourlyWage * (hoursWorked - overtimeHours)
```

Additionally, you shouldn't recalculate in your `total`; instead, just add regular and overtime.

Finally, as @CodeMonkey notes, you're unconditionally assuming that the person is working overtime. Here's what I suggest instead:

```
if(hoursWorked > 40) {
    regularHours = 40;
    overtimeHours = regularHours - 40;
} else {
    regularHours = hoursWorked;
    overtimeHours = 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to take into account that if you ever get hoursWorked less than 40 you'll end up with negative overtime and negative income! :-)

Comment: Yes.  I figured that.  I put in my System.out to not display overtime if it is less than or equal to 0.

Comment: @TheEliteTech Your calculations will still be wrong; you need to account for overtime/not-overtime in a manner such as I showed.

Comment: I just figured that out right before I came back to check this post.  I agree.  Thank you.